"Not a constructor" instantiating class in Gnome-shell >= 45
Can someone tell me how to create a basic class in Gnome-shell >=45?
The following code gives me an error:
class Conf {

     constructor(metadata) {
     
     }
}

In the main enable() part from 'Extension.js' file I call the class...
this.config = new Conf(metadata);

The error it throws is: TypeError: Conf is not a constructor
